# Android grid view scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I want to implement a grid view with a lot of icons with scrolling.

I have done that part now I want to implement the scrolling in such a way that firstly my screen shows first 6 icons and when I scroll it shows the next 6 icons (i.e the previous icons should not be visible). In short want my grid view to look like the Android home screen menu grid.

Comment: Scrolling is the default behavior of gridviews. You'll just have to arrange the size and layout of the buttons so that you have only 6 showing.

Comment: you are not getting my point....i know that scrolling is default but my question is that when i scroll i want to display next 6 items...just like scrolling in  main menu of android.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now i understand.

I think you could use a `viewflipper` that contains all your `gridviews`. The `viewflipper` could go through the different `gridviews` on a flick, for instance.

However, i would be conscious of how many `gridviews` you are adding. I am not familiar with how the `viewflipper` inflates views. In the worst case, you'll be inflating all the `gridviews` at once.

Comment: all the data in the grid view would be dynamic...and i would be using only one grid view.

Comment: i'm not sure you can achieve this animation with only one grid view, without the grid items disappearing to early or appearing to late. Perhaps you could use two (if you can flick one direction) or three (if two) to get good visual effects.